# Underscore templating with jade loops

Tags: underscore.js, pug

I'm running express with jade for templating, and backbone/underscore on the client-side code. I'd like to use a jade loop to iterate through an array, and construct divs for each of them.

```
  .members
    each elem in <%= members %>
      .member elem
```

Of course this won't work since the jade template is compiled and served by express... Any solutions, short of just formatting members separately and inserting it like this? I'd prefer not to compile jade on the client side either.

```
  .members
    <%= members %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If 'members' is a server-side variable, why wouldn't you just use this?

```
.members
    each elem in members
      .member elem
```

Edit: Ah I see, so if you're trying to get it on the client side, you can do something along the lines of:

```
script
  var members = #{JSON.stringify(members)};
```

Then, you have 'members' as a variable client-side and you can do whatever you want with it (including rendering it in an underscore template).

Comment: Apologies, members is a variable that's retrieved by the client by an AJAX request.

Comment: Gotcha, updated answer to reflect. Check the exact syntax, but it should be something like that.